# Emacs: format current file and keep the cursor position

Tags: emacs, format

I don't get a good answer after a short google-searching, so I ask it here.

Normally, when I want to format current file, I will do:

```
c-x h c-m-\
```

It formats current file, but I lose my cursor position. For example, I'm editing a long file, and I'm in line 157 now. When I reformatted the file, I found my cursor jumped to line 1. I've to move it manually to line 157, which is not convenient.

How can I do it?

Comment: The chosen answer solves your problem.  But I would take this opportunity to learn more about the mark-ring.  <kbd>C-u C-SPC</kbd><kbd>C-u C-SPC</kdb> would also solve this and is more composable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this function and bind it to a single keypress:

```
(defun indent-current-buffer ()
    (interactive)
    (indent-region (point-min) (point-max)))
```

Answer (score 5):

The general way to solve such problems in Emacs is as follows:

```
C-SPC C-SPC ...dowhatyouwant... C-u C-SPC
```

The C-SPC C-SPC part pushes the current position on the mark ring, and then the C-u C-SPC pops that position back from the mark ring.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly set the mark in this case because movement to the beginning/end of the buffer pushes point into mark-ring (as a convention).

Answer (score 1):

From my .emacs (seems to be taken from http://tuxicity.se/emacs/elisp/2010/05/07/clean-up-buffer-or-region-in-emacs.html or similar):

```
(defun clean-up-buffer-or-region ()
  "Untabifies, indents and deletes trailing whitespace from buffer or region."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (unless (region-active-p)
      (mark-whole-buffer))
    (untabify (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (indent-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
      (delete-trailing-whitespace))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c n") 'clean-up-buffer-or-region)
```

This does a little more than you want, but I usually find the extra bits of functionality (untabifying and removing trailing whitespace) useful.

Comment: `untabifying and removing trailing whitespace` is quite useful, thank you